Error in adding headless component to a page using ExperienceEditor
I am having sitecore 10.1 with headless implementation using Angular as frontEnd. I have frontEnd implementation of the component taken code and deployed to WWW root. When I add the component using experience Editor I get the popup message "An Error Occured."
Error
SuspectedError that DOM not finding rendering
SuspectedError Error JS
Want a fix for this and the cause of this error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There is no such code that I have written. I have attached images of the error, its about error in Experiene-Editor.
